# Clang regression or vectorization on single type

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

I was screwing around on godbolt and found a strange difference between what clang generates for unsigned shorts.
https://godbolt.org/g/36fgsT

If `limit` is anything other than unsigned short, it has vastly less output. It only happens on clang 3.5 and above with `-O2` or `-O3`.

I don't know enough assembly to know if it's a regression or vectorization, but in either case it seems strange that it only happens for this specific case.

Comment: Could you make the title a bit more specific to the problem case

Comment: It doesn't happen only on one type, it actually happens whenever the index type and limit are of the same type, and occasionally even when they're not. I would be curious to know why that's the case.

Comment: Maybe not directly related, but the generated code is a lot more complex than it need be, because of the possibility that `s` aliases the other globals. If you change `main` to `int f(u16 limit, i64 *__restrict s, i64& s0, i64& s1) ` and remove the globals , all 3 codes get a lot simpler

Comment: @M.M. I'm not sure what you mean by complex, but when I do what you suggest with restrict, the assembly is significantly longer (for clang 3.9) then in the original example. Probably because the compiler is doing even more sophisticated optimization, leading to an even tighter main loop but more code before/after. The main reason that the clang3.9 code is complex relative to the rest is because it has two loops: a 4 fold vectorized one, and another for the leftovers.

Comment: @NirFriedman the assembly is significantly shorter for all 3 when I make the suggested change in OP's link. [My change](https://godbolt.org/g/0d9DIT)

Comment: @M.M Right, so I just added restrict to s, but did not change the globals. The reason why your exact suggestion simplifies the code, is simply because now the `s0` and `s1` can alias each other, which disables more sophisticated optimizations, and reduces the vectorization from 4 to 2. If you add restrict on `s0` and `s1` in your suggestion, the code will get bigger again. In these examples, bigger code is actually usually faster code, indicative of better optimizations. So it's a bit misleading to say: "more complex than it need to be". More complex here is usually better.

Comment: @NirFriedman I see.  So perhaps the answer to OP's question is that clang 3.9 is generating faster code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126776/discussion-between-nir-friedman-and-m-m).

Comment: I don't know why exactly the difference occurs, but I will tell you that it is indeed vectorization and not regression. When it comes to trivial loops, usually more assembly is actually faster code. It comes from loop unrolling, which creates more instructions, and then the necessity of handling the last few cases not divisible by the unroll factor. Here, clang 3.9 has a tight loop of only 14 instructions unrolled 4x, 3.5 instructions per iteration. This is twice as good (or more) as older clang, or gcc.

Comment: Yes, this is loop unrolling. There is no vectorization kicking in because of possible aliasing (using global variable is always terrible for the optimizer)

Comment: @Joky Thanks for the correction, I was using vectorization and unrolling interchangeably which is of course wrong.